# jQuery screen width script

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using jQuery and Bootstrap with some articles stored in a database. My page displays an article divided into sections, each section with its own header.

I just discovered that I collapse all the sections by default (so the viewer only sees the headers, which they can click to reveal the text) by simply pasting this at the bottom of the page:

```
<script> 
    $('.collapse').collapse()
</script>
```

That's exactly what I've been trying to do, except I only want to collapse the sections in mobile devices. So I just wrote a script that should collapse the sections only in monitors less than 450 pixels wide...

```
<script> 
    if( $(window).width() < 450 ) {
    $('.collapse').collapse()
    } else {
    $('.collapse').show()
    }
</script>
```

The only problem is it doesn't work; the sections are expanded at all screen widths. If I change the less-than sign to more-than, then the sections are collapsed at all screen sizes.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

Thanks for the tips, but I've never heard of a "doc ready block" before. I followed your examples and Google's for more examples, but it still isn't working for me. Here are the scripts I tried:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 if( $(window).width() < 450 ) {
    $('.collapse').collapse()
 } else {
    $('.collapse').show()
 }
});
</script>
```

And the other one...

```
<script>
$(function (){
   $('.collapse').toggle($(window).width() < 450);
});
</script>
```

**EDIT #2**

Wow, this has been one of the most helpful discussions, even though nothing works for me the way it should. I finally achieved my goal by modifying the JavaScript function to this:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
 if ($(window).width() >= 450) {
 $('.collapse').show();
 } else {
 $('.collapse').collapse().collapse('show');
 }
});
</script>
```

However, things fall apart when I replace my CSS and JS files with the four files linked to in one of answers below. I figured I'd better keep up with the latest technology, so I copied my page and stripped it down, removing all the CSS and JS that might conflict with those four files.

This time I made it work by modifying the script again:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
if ($(window).width() <= 450) {
$('.show').collapse();
} else {
$('.collapse').collapse().collapse('show');
}
});
</script>
```

However, my glyphicons stopped displaying, so I have to troubleshoot that now. But all the tips below were very helpful; it was hard choosing a best answer.

P.S. I just tested Shashank's code again in my stripped down page and discovered it is working.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 if( $(window).width() < 450 ) {
    $('.collapse').collapse('hide');
 } else {
    $('.collapse').collapse('show');
 }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrap your code in the `ready` block and change it like below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if( $(window).width() < 450 ) {
        $('.collapse').collapse('hide');
    } else {
        $('.collapse').collapse('show');
    }
});
```

Also, you can put the class `collapse` in your both the column content so that it can be hidden by default till Javascript/jQuery executes.

Below is the working snippet. If that doesn't work, try this [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/TC7nhbLTFAilSlopPCpN?p=preview) I created. Try resizing the output window and then run the code in Plunkr to see the expected result.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log('Width: ', $(window).width());

  if ($(window).width() < 450) {
    $('.collapse').collapse('hide');
  } else {
    $('.collapse').collapse('show');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <h1><a href="#collapse1" data-toggle="collapse">Header 1</a></h1>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapse1">
      Some content 1
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <h1><a href="#collapse2" data-toggle="collapse">Header 1</a></h1>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapse2">
      Some content 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great examples, but I can't get either one to work. I edited my question to show how I wrote the script.

Comment: Awesome! I'll have to download those .js and .css files you linked to and give it another try. I'm at a WiFi cafe that's closing in just a couple minutes, so I have to run. I'll probably choose this as the correct answer tomorrow.

Comment: Sure. I've updated the answer with a working plunkr. Give it a try for expected result.

Answer (score 0):

#### Updates:

*If I change the less-than sign to more-than, then the sections are collapsed at all screen sizes.*

Then I guess you need `lte` which should be:

```
 if($(window).width() <= 450){
 //-----here-----------^
```

Seems that you need a doc ready block for it and use `.toggle(condition)`:

```
  $(function (){
       $('.collapse').toggle($(window).width() < 450);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

if you only want to hide all the content and want to display header on page load then you can also use css media query as well. this is the fastest way.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 450px) {
     .collapse{
          display: none;
     }
}
```

Comment: Thx - That would also be the simplest way. In fact, I think I was doing something similar originally; I don't know why it stopped working. I tried your style in both my original page and a copy that I stripped down, but it doesn't work for me. I'm still playing with it, but I haven't figured out what I'm doing wrong yet.

Comment: @DavidBlomstrom I think you need to check your css order. may be something overwrite your css or at last try with !important. I know this is not good way but atleast you know that your media query condition is applied or not.